# gpg: Sorry, we are in batchmode - can't get input

Tags: gnupg, gpg-signature

I'm on `macOS Catalina 10.15.6`
I'm using gpg to sign a file

```
gpg --sign file.txt
```

But has error:

```
gpg: Sorry, we are in batchmode - can't get input
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf` file (I use vim), delete the word `batch`

```
vi ~/.gnupg/gpg.conf
```

Press `dd` to delete a line, and `u` to undo. Press `:wq` to save changes.